# Count of Null and Not Null values in all the columns of a table for column names with spaces

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a procedure that will give null and non null count of all the columns in any table. 
The results will look like below:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| TableName   | ColumnName          | ColumnPosition| NullCount | NotNullCount |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| Client_Data | [Client Description]|   1           | 3         | 7            |
| Client Data | [zKey]              |   2           | 0         | 10           |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I have tried the following code and it works for most tables.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Null_NotNull_Count] 

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = 'Client_data'
DECLARE @COLUMN_Name NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..[dbo].[Null_NotNull_Count] ') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[Null_NotNull_Count] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Null_NotNull_Count]  
(TableName sysname
, ColumnName sysname 
, ColumnPosition int 
,NullCount int 
, NonNullCount int)

 SELECT @sql += 'SELECT  '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TableName 
 ,'''+[COLUMN_NAME]+''' AS ColumnName
 ,  '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),ORDINAL_POSITION)+''' AS ColumnPosition
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME+' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountNulls 
 ,COUNT(' +COLUMN_NAME+') CountnonNulls FROM '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+';'+ CHAR(10)

 FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
 AND   TABLE_NAME = @Table

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Null_NotNull_Count]
 (TableName 
, ColumnName 
, ColumnPosition 
,NullCount  
, NonNullCount)  

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

 SELECT * 
 FROM [dbo].[Null_NotNull_Count]
```

However, if a table contains column names which have spaces in between them, like " Client Description" in the above example, then the code doesn't work.
The following error message occurs:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 21
'Client' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Description'.
```

So, I need a solution as to how to modify the code so that it also takes column names which have spaces in them.

Comment: `QUOTENAME` function will solve your problems. I can see that you are already using it. Just add it to all places, where you use `COLUMN_NAME` or `TABLE_NAME`